# Auto pushing from local gitlab server to gitlab online

Tags: git, gitlab

Currently I am using gitlab online for source control for all my projects. I am concerned about future problems like gitlab being hacked etc. Not saying it's likely but a concern. So I want to install gitlab on a server on my LAN that myself and my friends push to. But having this as a sole backup server also concerns me in case it gets stolen or dies. Is there a way that we can all push to this back up server and have this sever push to the gitlab online server automatically without any configuration needed on the dev PCs? The solution would need to handle push failures to gitlab online in case gitlab online is offline due to updates or network failures. They can't get out of sync with each other. So it should realise that there is a failure and retry later. It will also need to work correctly with git-annex or another large file support system. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest solution**

Add multiple `pushUrls` to your remote (one for your local, the other for gitlab.com)

```
git remote set-url --add --push origin git://your_local_repo_url
git remote set-url --add --push origin git://your_gitlab_com_repo_url
```

You're trading a little bit of complexity on the clients (all the clients actually pushing need this configured if you really want an all-time complete backup, if that's not a necessity, clients who have the config will eventually sync the two when they push), for *a lot* of simplicity by not having to deal with sync issues after a "successful" push (if one of the push fails, you will know it when pushing - failing fast)

**Other solutions**

- use an hook on your local server to push to gitlab.com.
- use a cron on your local server to push to gitlab.com.

In both cases, you will need some retry mechanisms + some massive cleverness to handle weird cases (unclean pushes ...)

Comment: Thank you. You've convinced me the first solution will be best. I assume I will need to add the additional push URLs on the client side for every git repository and it can't be a global setting. Secondly what happens if one push fails and one succeeds? Let's assume that one of the servers went down so the push failed. Then later the server came back up. What needs to happen at client side to get the two servers back in sync? Especially if more work has since been done and a second successful push was sent to the other server? Thanks